# Excel Pivot depending upon Header values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a Pivot table in excel and below is my scenario. 
I have an excel sheet with 5 columns where columns 1,2,3 is having 3 different persons names( person1, person2,person3) as header and it's corresponding values will be either 'yes' or 'No'. column 4 is having amounts and columns 5 will have the share for each person. The share is calculated depending on the value(yes/No) that was present in the 1st three columns and the formula I am using for this is

```
      (D1/COUNTIFS(A1:C1,"Yes")) 
      i.e., dividing the (amount/ count( of persons having Yes value))

 Person1    Person2 Person3 Amount  PerHeadShare
 Yes        Yes     No       200         100
 Yes        Yes     Yes      300         100
 No         Yes     No       200         200
 No         No      Yes      100         100
```

Now My requirement is to create a pivot table with two columns

- column1 should have 3 rows with Person1,Person2 and Person3
- column2 should have sum of the share of amount each person is having

  ```
  Name          Sum
  Person1       200
  Person2       400
  Person3       200
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any experience with SQL, you can try something like this:

Data tab > From Access > change file filter to `All Files (*.*)` and select your Excel file > Open > OK > select PivotTable Report, New Worksheet, and then Properties... > Definition Tab > Command Type: SQL and enter this in Command Text:

```
SELECT Name, Sum( PerHeadShare ) As [Sum] FROM (
    SELECT 'Person1' As Name, Person1 AS y, * FROM [Sheet1$] UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Person2' As Name, Person2 AS y, * FROM [Sheet1$] UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Person3' As Name, Person3 AS y, * FROM [Sheet1$] ) 
WHERE y = 'Yes'
GROUP BY Name
```

OK > OK > Drag the Name field to Row Labels, drag the Sum field to Values, and then rename the headers in the PivotTable.

In the Command Text "Sheet1" has to be changed to the name of the sheet where the data is with a $ after it, or named range without $ like `[named Range]`, or specific range in the sheet like `[Sheet1$B2:F6]`

If you have Excel 2010 or above, this can be a bit easier with Power Query or PowerPivot (I have Excel 2007 so I can't try it).

Comment: I have followed the steps as per your suggestions and I am getting an error with description "No Value given for one or more required parameters"... My sheet name is same as given in the query that is Sheet1... so i kept the query as it is. I tried to give the range as well like Sheet1$A1:C5 but no luck

Comment: Can you try it with just `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]`. The usual reason for that error is misspelled name.

Comment: Perfect!! It is working... It's my mistake... the query is perfectly working... one of the column name is spelled wrongly in my sheet that is causing the issue. thank you once again @Slai

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's what you wanted. It´s still quite a lot of manual work. In my opinion your current data structure isn't very suitable for pivot table, but I might be wrong and would love to learn how to do it with pivot table..

1. Copy the first 3 colums of names and paste somewhere else
2. Then enter the formula in A8 and expand to the rest of the fields:
   [image]
3. Convert the range A7:C11 to values
4. Paste it somewhere else as transposed
   [image]
5. sum in the additional column

Comment: I got your point but that needs a lot of manual work and efforts. I was able to achieve what you have mentioned in another way by using the SUMIFS function. But that is not what I am looking for. I want to achieve this by using pivot table with out need to copy and paste my original data. Any suggestion or solution are greatly welcome. and thank you once again for your time

Comment: Yeah, I thought so.. Let's see if you get what you want. I am looking forward to learn that as well.